# Are unmatched end tags enough to stop IE11 submitting a form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a page with a form, split into two halves with layout divs. The right hand side dynamically generates inputs based on a previous choice by the user as to how many users they are booking in.

The whole thing is handled by PHP. The form action is set to the page itself. On submission the form is validated and if this passes the user is redirected on to the next step. If the validation fails, error messages are generated appropriately.

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but *not* in IE11 *except* when set to IE8 compatibility mode. In IE11 (10 and 9 compatibility modes too), absolutely nothing happens when I click the submit button. No errors are logged to the console, nothing is submitted, the page does not reload. In IE8 mode, it works fine.

The only console warnings that occur on page-load are two unmatched end tags. The first mismatch it finds is the first closing `</div>` tag. The second mismatch is the closing `</form>` tag.

```
<div class="6u">
    <form id="buy-form" name="details" action="booking3.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter Billing Details</legend>
            <label for="first_name" class="register">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="first_name" class="textbox booking required" size="20" maxlength="20"
                   value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['first_name'])) {
                       echo $_SESSION['first_name'];
                   } ?>"/><br/>
            <label for="last_name" class="register">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="last_name" class="textbox booking required" size="20" maxlength="20"
                   value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['last_name'])) {
                       echo $_SESSION['last_name'];
                   } ?>"/><br/>
            <label for="email" class="register">E-mail Address</label>
            <input type="email" id="emai" name="email" class="textbox booking required" size="20" maxlength="60"
                   value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
                       echo $_SESSION['email'];
                   } ?>"/><br/>
            <label for="telephone" class="register">Telephone</label>
            <input type="text" id="tel" name="telephone" class="textbox phonenumber booking required" size="20"
                   maxlength="20" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['telephone'])) {
                    echo $_SESSION['telephone'];
                } ?>"/><br/>
            <label for="address">Billing Address</label>
            <textarea class="order required" name="address"><?php if (isset($_SESSION['address'])) {
                    echo $_SESSION['address'];
                } ?></textarea>
        </fieldset>
</div>
<?php
if ($_SESSION['userno'] >= 1) { // if more than one user is selected, display text boxes to take extra user details
    echo '<div class="6u content content-right">';
    if ($_SESSION['userno'] == 1) {
        echo '<span>Please enter the name, e-mail address and telephone number of your user.</span><br/>';
    } else {
        echo '<span>Please enter the names, e-mail addresses and telephone numbers of your '.$_SESSION['userno'].' users.';
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $_SESSION['userno']; $i++) { //create textboxes for the appropriate amount of users based on userno selection
        echo '<fieldset><legend>User '.($i + 1).'</legend>';
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo '<label class="register">As Billing Details</label><input id="userisbooker" type="checkbox" class="booking"/><br/>';
        }
        echo '<label for="userFname[]" class="register">First Name: </label><input type="text" id="fname'.$i.'" name="userFname[]" class="textbox booking required" value="';
        if (isset($_SESSION['userFname'][$i])) {
            echo $_SESSION['userFname'][$i];
        }
        echo '"/><br/>';
        echo '<label for="userLname[]" class="register">Last Name: </label><input type="text" id="lname'.$i.'" name="userLname[]" class="textbox booking required" value="';
        if (isset($_SESSION['userLname'][$i])) {
            echo $_SESSION['userLname'][$i];
        }
        echo '"/><br/>';
        echo '<label for="userEmail[]" class="register">E-mail Address: </label><input type="email" id="email'.$i.'" name="userEmail[]" class="textbox booking required" value="';
        if (isset($_SESSION['userEmail'][$i])) {
            echo $_SESSION['userEmail'][$i];
        }
        echo '"/><br/>';
        echo '<label for="userTel[]" class="register">Telephone: </label><input type="text" id="tel'.$i.'" name="userTel[]" class="textbox booking required" value="';
        if (isset($_SESSION['userTel'][$i])) {
            echo $_SESSION['userTel'][$i];
        }
        echo '"/><br/>';
        echo '</fieldset>';
    }
    echo '<input class="button button-alt" type="submit" name="submit" value="Next >"/></form>';
}
?>
</div>
```

What is causing this problem in IE11? Are these two mismatched tags (which seem matched to me) enough to banjax the whole page?

Comment: Sooo... your HTML is invalid, and something doesn't work? I'd stop arguing about what exactly breaks how when where, and just fix the HTML instead.

Comment: I can't see where the HTML is invalid...

Comment: move the `</form>` OUTSIDE of the `if` statement.
If you start a form, you will have to close it either way.
I'm actually surprised you specify IE as the browser that won't work, since this should not work on any browser if you ask me.

Comment: @user3181236 You could just copy/paste the HTML sources to a W3C validator online and you'll get the errors

Comment: @timothygroote I've done that - no dice. In fact, the closing `</form>` tag was originally outside the if statement - I only moved it in while troubleshooting and forgot to move it out again.

Comment: Also try to follow the IPO-Model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_Model) . Do all the processing before the output. That will help you to clean up your mess by not mixing PHP & HTML that heavy

Comment: you're running into even more problems : you close the `<div>` element (the one you started the form tag in) way before terminating the form tag. i'm surprised any browser can figure out how this should have looked at all.

Comment: @TimothyGroote Ok, so I've removed the `div` tags that separated the form into two halves and that works - thank you! What would be the correct way to arrange a form into two columns?

Comment: additionally (i don't know what impact this has on the design though) you could move the definition of `<div class="6u content content-right">` (and its closing tag) outside of the PHP section entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should be ; do not close the element you're starting a form in before closing the form first.

```
<form id="buy-form" name="details" action="booking3.php" method="post">
    <div class="6u">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter Billing Details</legend>
            <label for="first_name" class="register">First Name</label><input type="text" id="fname" name="first_name" class="textbox booking required" size="20" maxlength="20" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['first_name'])){echo $_SESSION['first_name'];}?>"/><br/>
            <label for="last_name" class="register">Last Name</label><input type="text" id="lname" name="last_name" class="textbox booking required" size="20" maxlength="20" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['last_name'])){echo $_SESSION['last_name'];}?>"/><br/>
            <label for="email" class="register">E-mail Address</label><input type="email" id="emai" name="email" class="textbox booking required" size="20" maxlength="60" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){echo $_SESSION['email'];}?>"/><br/>
            <label for="telephone" class="register">Telephone</label><input type="text" id="tel" name="telephone" class="textbox phonenumber booking required" size="20" maxlength="20" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['telephone'])){echo $_SESSION['telephone'];}?>"/><br/>
            <label for="address">Billing Address</label><textarea class="order required" name="address"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['address'])){echo $_SESSION['address'];}?></textarea>
        </fieldset>

    </div>

        <?php
            if ($_SESSION['userno'] >= 1){ // if more than one user is selected, display text boxes to take extra user details
                echo '<div class="6u content content-right">';
                if ($_SESSION['userno'] == 1){
                    echo '<span>Please enter the name, e-mail address and telephone number of your user.</span><br/>';
                } else{
                    echo '<span>Please enter the names, e-mail addresses and telephone numbers of your '.$_SESSION['userno'].' users.';
                }
                for ($i = 0; $i < $_SESSION['userno']; $i++){ //create textboxes for the appropriate amount of users based on userno selection
                    echo '<fieldset><legend>User '. ($i+1).'</legend>';
                    if ($i == 0){
                        echo '<label class="register">As Billing Details</label><input id="userisbooker" type="checkbox" class="booking"/><br/>';
                    }
                    echo '<label for="userFname[]" class="register">First Name: </label><input type="text" id="fname'.$i.'" name="userFname[]" class="textbox booking required" value="'; if(isset($_SESSION['userFname'][$i])){echo $_SESSION['userFname'][$i];} echo'"/><br/>';
                    echo '<label for="userLname[]" class="register">Last Name: </label><input type="text" id="lname'.$i.'" name="userLname[]" class="textbox booking required" value="'; if(isset($_SESSION['userLname'][$i])){echo $_SESSION['userLname'][$i];} echo'"/><br/>';
                    echo '<label for="userEmail[]" class="register">E-mail Address: </label><input type="email" id="email'.$i.'" name="userEmail[]" class="textbox booking required" value="'; if(isset($_SESSION['userEmail'][$i])){echo $_SESSION['userEmail'][$i];} echo'"/><br/>';
                    echo '<label for="userTel[]" class="register">Telephone: </label><input type="text" id="tel'.$i.'" name="userTel[]" class="textbox booking required" value="'; if(isset($_SESSION['userTel'][$i])){echo $_SESSION['userTel'][$i];} echo'"/><br/>';                                      
                    echo '</fieldset>';
                }
                echo '<input class="button button-alt" type="submit" name="submit" value="Next >"/>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected - because the first `<div class="6u">` isn't closed until after the second one, the second `<div class="6u content content-right">` is lying _inside_ the first, rather than next to it.

Comment: aha, let me fix that. one sec

Comment: there. the trick is to start the form before you start the divs that split it in two, and close it after them.

Comment: Ah, of course! `<divs>` are fine _within_ forms. I actually knew that, too <facepalm>. Thanks very much for your help.